# GTK# + WebKit + Windows

Tags: c#, windows, mono, webkit, gtk#

I have developed a GTK# application that makes use of webkit-sharp to edit email templates. This application works in Linux but when it is run in Windows it does not work. I am using the webkit-sharp.dll from Linux in Windows. The error that I am getting is:

```
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'WebKit.WebView' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'webkit-1.0': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at WebKit.Download.webkit_download_get_type()
   at GtkSharp.WebkitSharp.ObjectManager.Initialize()
   at WebKit.WebView..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at WebKit.WebView..ctor()
   at MainWindow..ctor()
```

I am guessing that webkit-sharp.dll only wraps the native libraries for WebKit. I do not know where to get "webkit-1.0". Is there a webkit-sharp.dll that is specific to Windows for GTK#?

Comment: I am having the same issue here, very interested in the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly that. I guess the webkit windows dll does not use gtk as rendering engine.
What I did was install the libwebkit dll provided by the suse mingw32 port and all of its dependencies.

You can see a full list of dependencies [here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/binary?arch=i586&filename=mingw32-libwebkitgtk-1.4.0-4.22.noarch.rpm&package=mingw32-libwebkitgtk&project=windows%3amingw%3awin32&repository=openSUSE_11.4)

At the time of doing it(1 year ago more or less) the rendering was not perfect, but it may have improved.

Comment: I ended up reprogramming the application in WPF. Was a shame as I lost the cross platform ability but time was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem...

Not tried this, but at http://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html

The site suggests:

1. Download webkit support libraries
2. Run the update-webkit script
3. Build webkit from source

I think this requires cygwin installed.

I'm just paraphrasing the site - not tried this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the Hello World example app to make sure everything is set up correctly in your Windows environment?

http://mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

You can also try some of the other example programs to make sure they function without error.

http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide

Seems like a common installation issue requires the addition of an environment variable in windows to get the assemblies loaded correctly:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General#Installation_Problems

Comment: The application worked fine in windows except for when editing email templates because of the gtk# webkit control.